# Java heap profiling seems to freeze during large file ingestion

Tags: java, performance, profiling, heap-memory

I am trying to profile a java 7 application running on a redhat machine. When I run it as follows:

```
java -agentlib:hprof=cpu=samples,depth=10,monitor=y,thread=y ...
```

a particular block of code that creates a table-type object by reading a very large gzipped text file line by line completes in about 6 minutes. When I run it like this:

```
java -agentlib:hprof=heap=sites,depth=10,monitor=y,thread=y ...
```

the same block takes several orders of magnitude more time to complete (I am estimating something like 24 hours)

Here's the method (part of a class) that reads in the file:

```
private static void ingestValues()
{
    int mSize = 30000;

    pairScoresTable = new float[mSize][];
    for (int i = 0; i < pairScoresTable.length; i++) {
        pairScoresTable[i] = new float[mSize];
        Arrays.fill(pairScoresTable[i], fillVal);
    }

    try
    {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                    new GZIPInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(rawPath)), "US-ASCII"));
        String line = null;

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { // file has 388661141 lines

            Float value = 0.0F;
            Integer i = 0;
            Integer j = 0;

            // extract value, i and j by parsing line...

            pairScoresTable[i][j] = value;
            pairScoresTable[j][i] = value;

        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return;
    }

    return;
}
```

So it basically reads a file each line of which is formatted to describe the position of a `value` in the 2d matrix `pairScoresTable`.

Why is there such a large difference in execution time? Is there a way to do heap profiling of this code faster without having to refactor it?

Comment: Have you tried using a professional tools like JProfile and YourKit? Just to rule out that it is not your method/JVM arguments at fault. Also, your using 2d array, surely that will eat up heaps space. What is your JVM settings?

Comment: Which specific settings are you referring to?

Comment: JVM runtime settings, I.e. heaps, newSize etc